# Resizing alert dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog which prompts the user to enter text within an EditText but the AlertDialog popup isn't as wide as I need it to be. This is what it looks like:
[image]

How do I make it wider?

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
  // Using the following constructor produces a desirable width but 
  // the wrong theme colors
  // AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

  final EditText edittext = new EditText(getContext());
  alert.setMessage("Enter Your Message");
  alert.setTitle("Enter Your Title");

  alert.setView(edittext);

  alert.setPositiveButton("Yes Option", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

    String YouEditTextValue = edittext.getText().toString();
   }
  });

  alert.setNegativeButton("No Option", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // what ever you want to do with No option.
   }
  });

  alert.show();
```

My attempt at a theme:

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorLightGray</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorDarkerGray</item>
</style>
```

Comment: create custom layout for your alert dialog

Comment: try setting parent layout of your custom xml  to relative layout. you can design and use custom layout and attach it to your dialog.

Comment: Try this `AlertDialog dialog_card = alert.create();
    Window window = dialog_card.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`

Comment: set runtime height as per device screen size

Comment: @Isaac Perez, don't use a Dialog for such operation, open a dedicated page, or use a [Modal Bottom Sheet](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment/). Dialogs can be problematic in the system lifecycle, especially in conjunction with system permissions, so you'll see crashes of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Set the customised Windowmanager layoutparams as per your need and you should be good to go. Do this after you call dialog's `show()`, Like :

```
alertDialog.show();
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new 
WindowManager.LayoutParams();

layoutParams .copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
layoutParams .width = 150;
layoutParams .height = 500;
layoutParams .x=-170;
layoutParams .y=100;
alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams );
```

Answer (score 0):

Once try this

```
 // Using the following constructor produces a desirable width but
        // the wrong theme colors
        // AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

        AlertDialog alertDialog =  new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom).create();

        final EditText edittext = new EditText(this);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Your Message");
        alertDialog.setTitle("Enter Your Title");

        alertDialog.setView(edittext);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Yes Option", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                String YouEditTextValue = edittext.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"No Option", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // what ever you want to do with No option.
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

        lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT; // or you can give fix size lp.width = 500
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```